# Adding element to page every X number of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops

I need to run this function every X number of posts and the page uses AJAX to load in new posts as you scroll down the page. I was hoping to use the function below using a for loop with the modulus operator but it doesn't seem to accomplish what i'm looking for. Any idea how to do this?

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
function adTileLoop(){
        var adTile = "<div class='new-box' id='article-tile'></div>";
        var adLoc = 11;
        var p = $('#article-tile');
        var tile = $('#article-tile:nth-child('+adLoc+')');
        for(var i = 0; i <= p.length; i++){
                        if(i % adLoc == 0){
                            $(tile).after(adTile);
                        }
        }
}
$('#content').live(adTileLoop);
}
```

Comment: use it after the success of ajax

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to create an infinite scolling effect, right?  Meaning when the user has scrolled past a certain post, you'd load more content and they'd just continue scrolling.

Comment: Does that sound right? Or am I totally off point?

Comment: I have continuous scrolling already in place but now I need to have an static post/ad that is loaded in every 5th post. So I've figured out how to get it to post but now it's posting duplicates, so everytime the ajax call is made every static post is duplicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to be careful to keep IDs unique.  The fact that you have `$("#article-tile")` and you are trying to select more than one is a mistake.  ID's must be unique.

Here's a better way to run over a bunch of divs with jQuery:

```
$("div").each(function() {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

You can then improve the selector to select only `nth-children` as you do in your question:

`$("div:nth-child(2)")` for example will get every other div on the page.

To retrieve the information about your posts specifically, use a selector specific to each post, something like: `$(".post:nth-child(2)")`.

As Ashirvad suggested in the comments, you can run this after a successful ajax call and you will be able to retrieve the updated information about your page.

Comment: I would add that in case you don't want to do for every div or if you are using html5 sections or paragraphs, whatever really:  Use a class to identify which elements should be search `$('.classname:nth-child(x)')`

Comment: @Dameo I had excluded that as I thought it would be obvious; I have added it in, thanks.